# Algorithms for numerical integration of functions which are zero in a "large part" of its domain

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to evaluate a definite integral of a function which is zero almost everywhere, for instance something like a Gaussian with an artificial cutoff, such that any function value below some threshold is returned as 0.

I don't know beforehand where the function is above this threshold, I only have a very rough estimate.

Now if I take a look on e.g. the [adaptive Simpson's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Simpson%27s_method) then it will estimate the whole integral as 0 if the first few recursive calls happen to be outside the region, where the function returns a non-zero value.

I guess I'll face the same problems with most adaptive integration methods...
So how is this problem usually solved.

Can you give me some keywords please?

Comment: Well, if it is "zero almost everywhere" the integral will be zero!  A gaussian with an artificial cutoff has non-trivial support where it is nonzero.

Comment: You need to elaborate your question, as such it has a trivial answer.

Comment: If I choose the integration bounds properly, such that f(xmin) !=0 and f(xmax) !=0, why would the definite integral be zero?

Comment: The phrase "almost everywhere" has a technical meaning in this context, which I don't think is what you mean. I think what you mean is that it is zero in a "large" part of its domain for some loose meaning of the word "large". Without knowing anything about where that might happen, this is indeed a problem, similar to any other problem where you are trying to integrate a function with serious regularity issues. It is just a bit more severe than the usual situation because it may be hard to detect that it is even there in the first place.

Comment: (Cont.) But knowing that it is there, you can revise your algorithm to keep dividing until you get something nonzero at the very least, and then maybe keep dividing after that.

Comment: The term "almost everywhere" has a specific meaning which it seems like you're unaware of; that is going to cause confusion in this question, because if a function is zero "almost everywhere" then its integral is zero. Probably it will help to edit your question to avoid that term.

Comment: @Ian I'm sorry, I was not aware of it... My first guess was to perform some kind of root-finding to adjust the given integrations bounds. As I know that my function is concave I'm sure that there are only two roots

Comment: @littleO Actually, even if the function is zero almost everywhere in the measure sense, the computed integral may be nonzero: numerical methods evaluate the integrand at finitely many points.

Comment: @Ian I've tried this...but some integrands are indeed zero everywhere and not even worth evaluating

Comment: @ODIUM I'm not sure I understand your meaning. Are you saying that you have the underlying representation as $g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) & |f(x)|>c \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ or whatever it is? Then you could try to find the crossover points where $|f(x)|=c$ and integrate on some domain determined by them. Or you could just use brute force as I suggested (keep refining until you find that narrow region that contributes, since you know it exists).

Comment: @Ian yes,l that's what Im trying to say.. Maybe this problem is similar to integrating discontinuous functions...I'll give it a try